# Center a large UIView using NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I am new to use Autolayouts, even this is my first try. Whatever I do with it, I end with a white screen as result. Here is my attempt.

I have a `UIView`, let me say a `parentView` of frame `(60, 154, 200, 200)`. It is a subview to `self.view`.

Then I have a dynamic view, say `dynamicView` of frame `(0, 0, 260, 100)` and a `label` of frame `(15, 25, 230, 50)` which is a subview to `dynamicView`.

When I add the `dynamicView` as subview to the `parentView`, it goes out of `parentView`'s bounds. So, I'd like to adjust the size of the `dynamicView` and its child(`label`) so that its position is center to the `parentView` and `dynamicView` is inside `parentView`'s bounds.

My first attempt was setting `clipsToBounds`, its not working in Xcode5, iOS7. So the next option is to achieve this using `NSLayoutConstraint`. I have no idea on it. I welcome your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'll just address the dyanmicView being part of the parentView issue, then let you go from there

**first**: if you are creating the view dynamically, then you're good to go, but if you've created it from storyboard, you'd have to detach it from it's parent then reattach it.. that's how you get rid of it's previous NSConstraints (that usually the storyboard introduces) that may conflict with your new ones.

you also gotta set it's `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to NO b/c that also can interfere with your nsconstraints.

I usually do those last two steps like so, using  [mapObjectsUsingBlock](https://github.com/abbood/NSArray-Addons) to make the whole tedious process of creating constraints a bit more pleasant and natural:

```
    [@[view_1, view_2, /../, view_n] mapObjectsApplyingBlock:^(UIView *view) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
        [view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [view setHidden:NO];
        [superView addSubview:view];
    }];
```

**then** before applying nsconstraints, you gotta make sure that the view you want the constraints to apply to is *already* attached to it's parent:

```
[parentView addSubview:dynamicView];
```

**then** you want to create a bindings dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *buttonBindingsDictionary = @{ @"parentView" : parentView,
                                            @"dynamicView" : dynamicView};
```

then you want to add the constraints using the [visual format language](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/formatLanguage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH3).. I also use `mapObjectsUsingBlock` here (i'll explain each constraint in english):

```
NSArray *buttonConstraints = [@[@"V:|-[dynamicView(>=200)]-|",
                                @"|-[dynamicView(>=260)]-|",
                                ] mapObjectsUsingBlock:^id(NSString *formatString, NSUInteger idx){
    return [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:formatString options:0 metrics:nil views:buttonBindingsDictionary];
}];
```

`V:|-[dynamicView(>=200)]-|` means that vertically speaking.. the upper and lower distance between `dynamicView` and it's parent should be equal.. also `dynamicView's` height should be no less than `200`

`|-[dynamicView(>=260)]-|` means that horizontally speaking.. the left and right distance between `dyanmicview` and it's parent should be equal.. also `dyanmicView's` width should be no less than `260`

*note:* you can do the math yourself and set exactly how much the left/right/bottom/top distance between `dyanicView` and it's parent.. this is just simpler.. but sometimes nsconstraints messes up and I gotta do it myself.

in that case it would look something like this where `x` is the distance you came up with:

```
V:|-x-[dynamicView(>=200)]-x-|
|-x-[dynamicView(>=260)]-x-|
```

then you gotta add the constraints to the parent view:

```
[parentView addConstraints:[buttonConstraints flattenArray]];
```

notice here i used [flatten array](https://github.com/abbood/NSArray-Addons), again that's a method from my library b/c i want to feed it a one level array, not an array of arrays.

and you're good to go!

**note:** i know that this may not work perfectly.. but it gives you the idea of what to do + some helper files. It takes some practice, and you should look at some of the [tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2) for sure.. i suggest you start with nsconstraints using storyboard (you can select a view.. then go editor>pin>.. then chose something.. get some immediate visual feedback.. also you can simulate what your views will look like in 3.5" displays vs 4.0" displays immediately on the storyboard by selecting the view controller, then going to attributes inspector and selecting different sizes under simulated metrics)

take your time bud, but one thing for sure: once you go nsconstraints you will never look back! it's totally worth it!

p.s. you can also [animate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622424/how-do-i-animate-constraint-changes) views using nsconstraints as well.. just in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Auto Layout Constraints is the best approach to what you are trying to achieve. Auto layout constraints are added automatically when you check the Use Autolayout option in the IB.

Check out this tutorial which tells more about auto layouts in iOS6
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

then you can check this link for the updated autolayout in iOS7
http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/auto-layout-updates-in-ios-7/