# Zoom to fit current location and annotation on map

Tags: swift, mapkit

I am new to swift (iOS programming in general) and am trying to figure out how to zoom a map out to fit 2 points on the map.

Currently I have

```
var zoomRect = MKMapRectNull;
var myLocationPointRect = MKMapRectMake(myLocation.longitude, myLocation.latitude, 0, 0)
var currentDestinationPointRect = MKMapRectMake(currentDestination.longitude, currentDestination.latitude, 0, 0)

zoomRect = myLocationPointRect;
zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, currentDestinationPointRect);
```

Which does nothing.

Do I have to apply `zoomRect` to the map somehow?

Comment: By the way, please note `MKMapRectMake` accepts parameters of type `MKMapPoint` which are units that are _not_ the same as latitude and longitude degrees (`CLLocationDegrees`).  Even though both are doubles, they are not in the same units.  To convert from `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to `MKMapPoint`, use the `MKMapPointForCoordinate` function.  But if you use the `showAnnotations` method, you don't need to do this conversion or create an `MKMapRect` manually.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680649/zooming-mkmapview-to-fit-annotation-pins for some Objective-C examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MKMapRectUnion` computes and returns a new rect, nothing more. You need to tell the mapView to set its visible area to that new rect:

```
myMapView.setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, animated: true)
```

Comment: @lveselovsky answer is not working for me in Swift 4, but thanks a lot,  Above question, and this answer is worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 36):

```
self.mapView.showAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations, animated: true)
```

Comment: Best answer! The other ones are overly complicated that seemed to not work in certain situations.

Comment: I don't think that `showAnnotations` zooms to fit all annotations AND the current location.

Answer (score 6):

Use below MKMapView extension-

```
extension MKMapView
{
    func fitAllMarkers(shouldIncludeCurrentLocation: Bool) {

        if !shouldIncludeCurrentLocation
        {
            showAnnotations(annotations, animated: true)
        }
        else
        {
            var zoomRect = MKMapRectNull

            let point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(userLocation.coordinate)
            let pointRect = MKMapRectMake(point.x, point.y, 0, 0)
            zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect)

            for annotation in annotations {

                let annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate)
                let pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0, 0)

                if (MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect)) {
                    zoomRect = pointRect
                } else {
                    zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect)
                }
            }

            setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8), animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That else block seems overdone. Why not get the users current-location annotation through `self.mapView.userLocation` then add it to your annotations list, and then user `showAnnotations` ?

Comment: @pnizzle, won't an annotation for the current location get drawn as a pin and show up at the same location as the current location circle drawn by the map view? or is there a way to make an invisible annoation?

Answer (score 3):

**For swift 3, iOS 10**

Get current location first, and using call back **didUpdateLocations** to configure the map. Add the following code in your view controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

private var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}



public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let last = newLocation {
        let userlongitude = last.coordinate.longitude
        let userlatitude = last.coordinate.latitude
        let newDistance = CLLocation(latitude: userlatitude, longitude: userlongitude).distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: YourAnnotation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: YourAnnotation.coordinate.longitude))
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(last.coordinate, 2 * newDistance, 2 * newDistance)
        let adjustRegion = self.mapView.regionThatFits(region)
        self.mapView.setRegion(adjustRegion, animated:true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`-[MKMapView showAnnotations:animated:]`

Comment: Do I put this after my code? is that objective c code?

Comment: Yes, this is a method signature. Basically make an `NSArray` containing your points, pass it as the first argument, and pass a `BOOL` for the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

As @lveselovsky said

```
self.mapView.showAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations, animated: true)
```

works perfectly.

If you are updating your UI before the map has loaded, you can put it in the delegate method like so:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    guard !mapZoomUpdatedOnce else {
        return
    }

    self.mapView.showAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations, animated: true)
    self.mapZoomUpdatedOnce = true
}
```

Boolean value only to make sure once it's updated the first time, it does not get updated again if the user navigates somewhere else on the map :)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 Fit all annotations in map.
It's the correct way.

```
func zoomMapaFitAnnotations() {

        var zoomRect = MKMapRectNull
        for annotation in mapview.annotations {

            let annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate)

            let pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0, 0)

            if (MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect)) {
                zoomRect = pointRect
            } else {
                zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect)
            }
        }
        self.mapview.setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 50, 50, 50), animated: true)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add MKMapViewDelegate and connect mapView delegate in ViewDidLoad

```
mapView.delegate =. self


func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: userLocation.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```