# Show all annotations in map without zooming-In in xcode 9 swift 4

Tags: swift

I am making an application in Xcode 9 swift 4 , my problem with my application is about in the map and annotations, I already plotted the annotations to their particular location with their particular coordinates(latitude,longitude),and when I run the application the map show only few of the annotations(not all annotations) but when I begin to zooming-in to the map by double tapping the screen of the iphone, the remaining annotation start to show one by one and some of the annotation only will show when I almost fully zoom-in in the map. How can I see all the annotations without zooming-in in the map , Hope you guys can help.
just comment your suggestions.

[the view when I run the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkdq1.png)

[the view when I zoom-in the map , I tap the an annotation(the bigger annotation) just to let you see that there is another annotation behind it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inIQZ.jpg)

Comment: I think you should look into something like this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157634/zoom-to-fit-current-location-and-annotation-on-map

Comment: check this code after adding your annotations .self.mapView.showAnnotations(self.mapView.annotations, animated: true)

Comment: sad to say but no luck :(

Comment: when I zoom-in it will show the other annotations, but when I zoom-out again the two nearest annotations will combine as one

Comment: Make sure you set `annotationView.displayPriority = .required` in your mapView:viewForAnnotation: delegate call