# Adjusting map view span to annotiation pins in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I wonder if Swift supports any faster way to do that without implementing arythmetics. I guess adjusting the map span to let user see all the annotation pins is not a rare problem.

I found this: [Zooming MKMapView to fit annotation pins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680649/zooming-mkmapview-to-fit-annotation-pins)
but it's a bit complicated in objective-c and seems to be a vulnerable solution. Did swift developers find any other way(or method) to deal with it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can target iOS 7 or above, you can use [showAnnotations:animated](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/showAnnotations:animated:), and pass in the map view's `annotation` property.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not sure how to pass the annotations, as an array of them?

Comment: Assuming your MKMapView is named `mapView`, I believe you can just past in `mapView.annotations`