# Determine proper zoom level on GMSMapView to fit all the locations needed?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, gmsmapview

In my iOS app I'm using GoogleMaps and APIs for maps and I'm not very familiar with it.

I know that with iOS native MKMapView you can set a visible map rect to fit all the points needed at a proper zoom level, like described here: [Zooming MKMapView to fit annotation pins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680649/zooming-mkmapview-to-fit-annotation-pins)

but I'm not sure how to do such thing for GMSMapView. Does anyone know how to do it?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this after setting up markers on the Map:

```swift
var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
for coordinate in testCoordinates {
    bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(coordinate)
}
let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 50)
mapView.animate(with: update)
```

Comment: Somehow this does not work for me. If I check bounds.isValid it returns "false". If I use GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: c1, coordinate: c2) => this works, but it takes only 2 coordinates.