# Show My Location point and one another point in single view (MKMapView)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-maps-api-3, mkmapview

I am using MKMapView and showing particular point on that map.

There is a button in my screen for finding My Location.now i want that when i click on MyLocation button both the point(My location and another point for particular location) should come in single screen .
****it should be like like : ****

------------------------------ [image]

so i have to calculate distance between myLocation (blue) and particular point (Red)

Any help please ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336370/positioning-mkmapview-to-show-multiple-annotations-at-once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something Similar ...

```
    //create new region and set map
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {latitude: yourLocation.latitude, longitude: yourLocation.longitude};
     MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(fabs(otherLocation.lattitude), fabs(otherLocation.longitude));
    MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};
    [self.mapView setRegion:region];
```

Comment: it is crashing . showing reason: 'Invalid Region <center:+23.05319800, +72.56401100 span:+44.34936142, -74.14461517>'

Comment: MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(fabs(otherLocation.lattitude), fabs(otherLocation.longitude));

Comment: but then it is showing other region , it shows near location 23.05319800 but not oter point.

Comment: my logic may be wrong but see this two property region and span , you need to adjust that , refer document or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show Direction in google maps you need current latitude & longitude and particular place lat & long,

Within Button touch action

```
 {          
  NSURL *strlist = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",c_lat,c_long,lat,long]];
       here //c_lat = current latitude
  //c_long = current longitude
  //lat = Particular place latitude
  //long = Particular place longitude
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:strlist];   
 }
```

If you want to show direction map within app,

Refer this tut

[Link for Direction Tut](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions)