# how can I set zoom level of map according to values of all lat long ,so I can see all that places in map iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am getting lat longs of different locations,and I want to set zoom (span) in a such a way that I can see all (locations) pins on a map.

Comment: Do you know in how many miles your all pins will be covered

Comment: it would be in any where a whole world .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much a dup of [Positioning MKMapView to show multiple annotations at once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1336370/191215).

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/7642526/191215 the most elegant.