# MapKit range zoom

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mapkit

Is there a way to view a map based on the range of annotations that you have? So that does not leave any pin out

```
//Map
mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 299, 406)];
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
region.center.latitude = [latitudeNumber doubleValue];
region.center.longitude = [longitudeNumber doubleValue];
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 
[mapView setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post:
[Positioning MKMapView to show multiple annotations at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336370/positioning-mkmapview-to-show-multiple-annotations-at-once)

Depending on how many annotations you're adding, you may have to tweak the code found in the linked answer to loop through all of your annotations to find the min/max values of lat/long.