# Positioning GMSMapView to show multiple annotations at once

Tags: ios, google-maps

My question is quite similar to [this, except MKMapView.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336370/positioning-mkmapview-to-show-multiple-annotations-at-once)
How can I do the same process(resize the map to fit all annotations/markers on screen at once) with Google Maps?
As I understand I have to convert MKCoordinateRegion to GMSProjection, is my way right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thats very simple, just:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) GMSMapView *mapView;

- (void)didTapFitBoundsWithMarkers:(NSArray *)markers
{
GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] init];;

for (GMSMarker *marker in markers) {
    bounds = [bounds includingCoordinate:marker.position];
}

GMSCameraUpdate *update = [GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds:bounds];
[self.mapView moveCamera:update];
[self.mapView animateToViewingAngle:50];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention.
When I posted question I couldn't find this method (`includingCoordinate`) in earler version of GMapsSDK.
And API didn't include the `GMSCameraUpdate` class