# How to load a KML file URL into Google Maps using iOS API?

Tags: ios, google-maps, kml, google-maps-sdk-ios

I've got Google Map embedded in a View Controller in a Map on an iPhone.  I can create my map using:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:39.93
                                                        longitude:-75.17
                                                             zoom:12];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

// use GPS to determine location of self
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
```

Now, I want to add a kml file (from a URL) that displays a route.  I would imagine there is something within GMSMapView to allow this either as a layer or something else, but I'm not having any luck.  I've seen the KMS Tutorial but that uses some other kit, MK something.  Anyway, is there a way I can load a KML file using the Google Maps for iOS API?

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is more than 1 year old but I couldn't find any solution, so I hope my solution will be useful.

You can load KML into GMSMapView using [iOS-KML-Framework](https://github.com/FLCLjp/iOS-KML-Framework). I've ported this code from a project that was using [KML-Viewer](https://github.com/FLCLjp/KML-Viewer)

Add method for parsing KML from the given URL, make sure you pass correct app bundle to dispatch_queue_create():

```
- (void)loadKMLAtURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    dispatch_queue_t loadKmlQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.app.kmlqueue", NULL);

    dispatch_async(loadKmlQueue, ^{
        KMLRoot *newKml = [KMLParser parseKMLAtURL:url];

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(kmlLoaded:) withObject:newKml waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}
```

Handle the KML parsing result or error:

```
- (void)kmlLoaded:(id)sender {
    self.navigationController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    __kml = sender;

    // remove KML format error observer
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:kKMLInvalidKMLFormatNotification object:nil];

    if (__kml) {
        __geometries = __kml.geometries;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.navigationController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            [self reloadMapView];
        });
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.navigationController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil)
                                                                message:NSLocalizedString(@"Failed to read the KML file", nil)
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        });
    }
}
```

Go over the geometry items from KML and add them to the GMSMapView as markers:

```
- (void)reloadMapView
{
    NSMutableArray *annotations = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (KMLAbstractGeometry *geometry in __geometries) {
        MKShape *mkShape = [geometry mapkitShape];
        if (mkShape) {
            if ([mkShape isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]]) {
                MKPointAnnotation *annotation = (MKPointAnnotation*)mkShape;

                GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
                marker.position = annotation.coordinate;
                marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
                marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker"];
                marker.title = annotation.title;
                marker.userData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", geometry.placemark.descriptionValue];
                marker.map = self.mapView;

                [annotations addObject:annotation];
            }
        }
    }

    // set bounds in next run loop.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] init];

        for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in annotations)
        {
            bounds = [bounds includingCoordinate:annotation.coordinate];
        }

        GMSCameraUpdate *update = [GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds:bounds];
        [self.mapView moveCamera:update];
        [self.mapView animateToViewingAngle:50];
    });

}
```

At the end of the last method we're [updating the camera view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17185153/2948350) to fit all the markers that were added to the map. You can remove this part if it's not needed.

Comment: You seem to be doing a lot more passing off to the main thread than is strictly required...

Comment: @Wain, you may be right. The original code is not mine, so I haven't had a chance to review its efficiency. Just ported it to Google Maps SDK yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

KML is not yet supported in the SDK. Please file a feature request in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Feature%20Request).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved similar problem using mentioned [iOS-KML-Framework](https://github.com/FLCLjp/iOS-KML-Framework).

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import "KML.h"

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView;

- (void)loadZonesFromURL:(NSURL *)url {

KMLRoot* kml = [KMLParser parseKMLAtURL: url];

for (KMLPlacemark *placemark in kml.placemarks) {
    GMSMutablePath *rect = [GMSMutablePath path];

    if ([placemark.geometry isKindOfClass:[KMLPolygon class]]) {
        KMLLinearRing *ring = [(KMLPolygon *)placemark.geometry outerBoundaryIs];

        for (KMLCoordinate *coordinate in ring.coordinates) {
            [rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude)];
        }

        GMSPolygon *polygon = [GMSPolygon polygonWithPath:rect];
        polygon.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:67.0/255.0 green:172.0/255.0 blue:52.0/255.0 alpha:0.3];
        polygon.map = self.mapView;

    }

}


}
```