# How to Load ".kml" on Google Maps using Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, xcode8

I  have integrated google maps in my iOS application. Now I want to load ".kml" file on that, how do it. ? Is there any API that can load ".kml" file if I give path. or I need to Use NSXML parser and do everything manually?.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how stable this library was but its good reputation so please go through this Library for `KML` parsing and use it into `Google map`.

**Library Link :** https://github.com/FLCLjp/iOS-KML-Framework

**Stack Help Link for KML :** [How to load a KML file URL into Google Maps using iOS API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303695/how-to-load-a-kml-file-url-into-google-maps-using-ios-api)

Hope above link will helps you to achieve `KML` integration.

Comment: thanks for the early reply , I have already gone through the 1st url, but after parsing I am unable to understand where I will get those values and how to give them to mapView. In android they are loading kml file to mapView.